# is this python async request improve performance compare normal blocking requests?

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await

```
async def fetch_single(url):  
    res=requests.get(url).json()
    return res

async def fetch_all(urls):  
    results=[]  
    for url in urls:  
        print ("url")  
        res=await fetch_single(url)  
        print("res")  
        results.append(res)     
    return res  
def async_main(urls):  
    return asyncio.run(fetch_all(urls))
```

Is above code faster than normal requests code,normal means no aync and await? 
If this is true,how? Because i find every print("res") is follow print ("url"),just like normal blocking code.

If I do not await fetch_single and just run it, should for loop be executed immediately without concern request response?

If the above code can not improve performance, what is the easiest way to improve performance using async and await for blocking lib like requests? especially when urls is not in a flat list but in deep nested dictionary.

Please do not provide ways in aiohttp , or multiprocessing(which is not compatible with gevent in server-side), or multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool(which is not async await)

Comment: Isn't the whole point of gevent to write synchronous code?

Comment: this is not the question about gevent,this is question about async and await

Comment: I think you shouldn’t use async-await if you use gevent because gevent will turn synchronous code into asynchronous one (from what I understand).